# jQuery shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any more elegant way to write that? :

```
var AllOperation = $('#menu > li.operation');
var Operation1= AllOperation[0];
$(Operation1).addClass('operation-first');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#menu > li.operation').first().addClass('operation-first')
```

Or

```
$('#menu > li.operation:first').addClass('operation-first')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target a specific element in a jQuery object you can use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

For the first one you should use 0 (*the method is 0 based*)

```
$('#menu > li.operation').eq(0).addClass('operation-first');
```

If you only want to target the first, you can use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method (*as mentioned in the other answers*)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#menu > li.operation:first').addClass('operation-first');`